# 71 players tournament. 9 matches each. Is it possible?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I'm trying to create an algorithm that will generate all matches for a tournament. I'm having trouble trying to match players for a 71 player tournament. Each player is supposed to have a total of 9 matches, no more, no less. Only 1 match against one enemy. No matter what I do, there's always one player left with 8 matches.

Is it even possible to have 9 matches each? How do I calculate that?

What would be a generic way to calculate if it's possible to have m matches for each player for a tournament of p players?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got $639=71\cdot9$ teams showing up for a game.  If you're expecting two teams per game, an odd number isn't going to work out for you.

Comment: So, basically, it's not possible to make a schedule with an odd number of teams and an odd number of matches? Either the number of teams or the number of matches need to be even? Right?

Comment: That's right.  I'm pretty sure that's sufficient as well as necessary, but I'm not positive.